# Is there a systematic way of resolving sequences of dots in figures?

Tags: sequences-and-series

http://bibliotecadigital.ilce.edu.mx/sites/telesecundaria/tsm01g01v01/u02t04s01.html

[image]

I wonder if there is a systematic way to get the formula of a sequence of dots in figures, to resolve it faster, and apply it to other figures.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the formula' and 'resolve it'?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean how can I get a formula for the lineal increment in dots, say for example, in the figure 50, how many dots will there be. The problem is that figures vary (different problems), so having the first 3 figures of the series, how can I get the formula of the linear increment

Comment: Just be counting it must be $2n+1$.

Comment: @copper.hat in this case it may be true, but I am looking for clear steps to get ANY formula of any figure that linear increments its 'dots'. For example, having a series of hexagons, with dots in the angles, you have the formula 4x+2. In the figure 1, 6 dots, in the figure 2, 10 dots (2 shared)

Comment: I don't know how to help unless you are more specific about the characterization of the figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the get the linear equation of type:

```
y=kx+b
```

In which, y is the number of total balls and x is the sequence element's number. If you have access to 2 elemnts and its corresponding number of balls simply solve this system of equations. For example, y(1)=6 and y(2)=10, then

```
| 6=k*1+b   <=>  |k=4
| 10=k*2+b       |b=2
```

So the final equation would be:

```
y=4x+2
```

If you wante to calculate element 50, replace x with that value and you have the total number of balls:

```
y=4*50+2=202
```

This is the same method applied when you know 2 dots in a linear graph.